# SQL Server variable scope in a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to declare a variable within an if/else statement in a SQL Server stored procedure. I understand that this is fairly impossible because SQL Server doesn't do memory management with respect to declaration of variables within procedures. Is there a way to have a variable scoped in an if/else statement, then redeclare a variable with the same name in another if/else statement? For example:

```
create procedure Foo
as
begin  
    if exists (x)
    begin
        declare @bob int
        set bob = 1
    end
    else
    begin
        declare @bob int
        set bob = 2
    end
end
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

From [books online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187953.aspx):

> The scope of a variable is the range of Transact-SQL statements that can reference the variable. The scope of a variable lasts from the point it is declared until the end of the batch or stored procedure in which it is declared.

However.  Nothing keeps you from doing this:

```
create procedure Foo as begin

declare @bob int

if exists (x)
begin
    set @bob = 1
end
else
begin
    set @bob = 2
end

end
```

Answer (score 9):

No, SQL is pretty funny/weird like that

**Declare the variable before the** `if  exists` **block of code**

so

```
declare @bob int 
set @bob = 2 

if exists(x) 
begin   
    set @bob = 1 
end
```

Now, take a look at these examples and try to guess what happens

```
WHILE 1 = 2 --not true of course
BEGIN
  DECLARE @VAR INT;
END
SET @VAR = 1;

SELECT @VAR;
```

This of course works, but it is not initialized every time

```
DECLARE @loop INT
SET @loop = 0

WHILE @loop <=6
BEGIN
        DECLARE @VAR INT
        SET @VAR = COALESCE(@VAR,0) + 1
        SET @loop = @loop +1
END

SELECT @VAR
```

Comment: I'm scratching my head over your `WHILE 1 = 2` example... how???

Answer (score 3):

is there some reason why you can't do :

```
declare @bob int 
if exists(x) 
begin   set @bob = 1 end 
else 
begin  set @bob = 2 end
```

Comment: Exactly what I was going to say. Sounds like OP is only trying to do this for the sake of formatting.

Comment: I think it's a bad particular example on the OP's point, there are certainly cases where a variable isn't leaving the scope of BEGIN/END and you may want to re-use a variable name within separate and restrictive scopes, and unfortunately this simply isn't available.

Comment: That is what i am currently doing. There isn't a technical reason why I want to do it the way I mentioned. I was wondering if it was possible.

Comment: @Yuck. Not just for formatting. I was working with some .net code and was curious if there was a way to scope variables in sql. Found out I didn't know if there is a possible way of doing it. I assumed there wasn't a way but i didnt know for fact or why you cant.

Answer (score 2):

You could resort to using dynamic SQL:

```sql
if exists (x)
begin
    exec sp_executesql N'
        declare @bob int
        set @bob = 1
    ';
end
else
begin
    exec sp_executesql N'
        declare @bob int
        set @bob = 2
    ';
end
```