# why block scope variables exist outside of block?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

i have the following stored procedure to test scope of variables

```
alter proc updatePrereq
    @pcntr int, 
    @pmax int
as
begin 

    if @pcntr = 1
    begin 
        declare @i int
        set @i= @pcntr
    end

    set @i=@pcntr
    select @i;
end
go
```

In the above script @i is declare in the if block only when the @pcntr value is 1. Assume the above stored procedure is called 5 times from this script

```
declare @z int
set @z = 1

declare @max int
set @max = 5

while @z <= @max
begin 
    exec dbo.updatePrereq @z, @max
    set @z = @z + 1
end
go
```

As i said earlier `@i` variable exists only when `@pcntr` is `1`. Therefore when i call the stored procedure for the second time and so forth the control cannot enter the if block therefore @i variable wouldn't even exist. But the script prints the value in `@i` in each iteration, How comes this is possible should it throw an error saying `@i` variable does not exist when `@pcntr` values is greater than `1`?

[here is video showing this issues](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZdmhR054jvU&feature=youtu.be)
thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The scope of a variable is the range of Transact-SQL statements that can reference the variable. The scope of a variable lasts from the point it is declared until the end of the batch or stored procedure in which it is declared. (Source :**[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187953.aspx)**)

Its scope  doesn't end at the `If satement`

Comment: in both cases gives the same results. But in my case it should be printing "1" and should throw an error for other iterations shouldn't it? But it did not!

Comment: should be, but it did not throw an error! that why i posted this! let me put a youtube video in a second

Comment: @PhillGreggan - Sorry first time didn't read your qusetion properly. The scope of variable doesn't end at the if condition. It scope is until the end of the batch or stored procedure

Comment: @NoDisplayName- End of the stored procedure is the end tag at the bottom of the stored procedure, am i correct? if so still it should ask for a fresh redeclaration of the @i variable on the second round so forth

Comment: @PhillGreggan - No it won't ask.  check this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5994957/sql-server-variable-scope-in-a-stored-procedure https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/537275/make-it-possible-to-declare-variables-that-are-only-visible-within-a-block