# Is there a performance impact declaring tempory tables in If Else Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on a sql server stored procedure which is used to generate excel based reports. Each and every report have to made using HTML and columns are differ. Is it ok to declare temporary tables in every if statement. I am using if.. else if approach for this...

Comment: If you mean different tables, then sure, do it, because you need different tables to begin with. If you mean redeclaring same tables in different `if` blocks, [that's not how t-sql works](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5994957/11683).

Comment: I mean different tables .. Thanks.. !!!