# if/else condition in select statement

Tags: sql-server

I want to verify if an employee exists in that client or not; if he does exist, then I want to show a message "success", else I want to show "invalid employee".

```
declare @Employeeid int

if @Employeeid = 1616
    select 
        @Employeeid = employeeindex 
    from 
        Employee_table
    where 
        clientid in (select Clientid 
                        from Employee_table 
                        where Clientid = 658)

    select * 
    from Employee_table 
    where Employeeid = @Employeeid

else
    raiserror ('Invalid Employee!', 16, 1)

return
```

This shows an error

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'else'.

Comment: Try to add the scopes to your 'if' by begin and end just as here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5994957/sql-server-variable-scope-in-a-stored-procedure

Answer (score 1):

Encloses a series of Transact-SQL statements so that a group of Transact-SQL statements can be executed. `BEGIN` and `END` are control-of-flow language keywords.

[Read here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/begin-end-transact-sql)

Query

```
declare @Employeeid int

if @Employeeid = 1616
begin
    select @Employeeid = employeeindex 
    from Employee_table
    where clientindex in (select Clientid 
                          from Employee_table 
                          where Clientid = 658)

    select * 
    from Employee_table 
    where Employeeid = @Employeeid
end
else
    raiserror ('Invalid Employee! ', 16,1)

return
```

Comment: 1616 exist in 658 and this query shows invalid employee

Comment: Well in this code block you have not set the value of EmployeeID before you check the value in the IF statement.  So EmployeeID is NULL, that is why is shows invalid employee

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/if-else-transact-sql

> Imposes conditions on the execution of a Transact-SQL statement. **The
>   Transact-SQL statement that follows an IF keyword** and its condition is
>   executed if the condition is satisfied: the Boolean expression returns
>   TRUE

Use BEGIN... END if need group statement for IF